# SQL EXCEPT Not Working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
; WITH cte AS
(SELECT p.BudgetNumber, t.MilestoneNumber FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT BudgetNumber FROM tblMilestones) p 
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT MilestoneNumber FROM tblMilestoneTemplate) t)

SELECT BudgetNumber, MilestoneNumber FROM cte 
EXCEPT (SELECT BudgetNumber, MilestoneNumber FROM tblMilestones)
ORDER BY BudgetNumber, MilestoneNumber
```

The query above creates all possible BudgetNumber and MilestoneNumber combinations using a cross join, and then attempts to locate combinations that are not in the tblMilestones table (I didn't create this database, I know the table prefixes are weird and this db isn't normalized).

There are no NULL entries in any of these fields. When I use this query with the EXCEPT clause above, I get some missing values (but not all), but I also get some non-missing values. When I change the EXCEPT to a LEFT JOIN, I get the same results.  When I change the EXCEPT to a WHERE NOT EXISTS, I get no results at all. Can anyone please help?

**[SQLFiddle Output](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/819e1/2/0)**:

```
| BUDGETNUMBER | MILESTONENUMBER |
|--------------|-----------------|
|      BA04001 |               0 |
|      BA04001 |              99 |
|      BA04005 |               0 |
|      BA04005 |              99 |
|      BA05001 |               0 |
|      BA05001 |              99 |
|      BA05002 |               0 |
|      BA05002 |              99 |
```

Comment: Your query seems to logically do what you are stating. You could simplify the cte quite a bit but it should do the same thing. Can you put together a sqlfiddle with table structures and enough sample data to replicate the issue?

Comment: Here it is: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/819e1/1

Note how it is not outputting 5.25 as a missing milestone for item **BA04001**, even though that milestone exists in tblMilestoneTemplate. When I run the same query on my SQL Server 2012, it does find 5.25 as missing, but it also shows 2.3 and 6.1 as missing, both of which clearly aren't as they exist in tblMilestones for item **BA04001**

Comment: I assume that the actual datatype in tblMilestones has a precision defined? When you don't define a precision on a numeric it becomes an int. select cast(5.25 as numeric)

Comment: Your fiddle is either broken or there is something wrong with your code because you have decimal places in your values but the datatypes do not support that level of precision.

Comment: Here is another fiddle using numeric datatypes with a defined precision. I used the exact query you posted in your question and it seems to work just fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8395a/2

Comment: You and Vladimir were completely correct. I have both the MilestoneNumber fields defined as 'float' in my development database, and it wasn't working there. Changed to numeric(10,4) and it works beautifully now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you would need to use `NOT EXISTS` correctly. You need specify where clause inside subquery to get correct result.

```
;
WITH    cte
          AS (
               SELECT p.BudgetNumber
                   ,t.MilestoneNumber
                FROM (
                       SELECT DISTINCT BudgetNumber
                        FROM tblMilestones
                     ) p
                CROSS JOIN (
                             SELECT DISTINCT MilestoneNumber
                                FROM tblMilestoneTemplate
                           ) t
             )
    SELECT BudgetNumber
           ,MilestoneNumber
        FROM cte t
        WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                            FROM tblMilestones s
                            WHERE t.BudgetNumber = s.BudgetNumber
                                AND t.MilestoneNumber = s.MilestoneNumber )
        ORDER BY BudgetNumber
           ,MilestoneNumber
```

Look at following two examples

```
DECLARE @NoPrecision AS TABLE ( MyNumber DECIMAL )
INSERT INTO @NoPrecision ( MyNumber ) VALUES ( 12345.123456789 )
SELECT * FROM @NoPrecision
```

output: 12345

```
DECLARE @Precision AS TABLE ( MyNumber DECIMAL(10,4) )
INSERT INTO @Precision ( MyNumber ) VALUES ( 12345.123456789 )
SELECT * FROM @Precision
```

output: 12345.1235

Comment: Thank you, but that is giving me the exact same results as the EXCEPT.

Comment: Looks like you had data type issue in SQL Fiddle, maybe same problem in SQL, when you declare numeric, decimal or float you need to specify level of precision. Check updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5f0d9/1

Comment: Very helpful, thank you Vladimir. I had both my MilestoneNumber fields as 'float' in my database, but changed to numeric (10,4) and it works now. Appreciate your help!